# Pyganim Help in Sidescroller Game

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I know how to use Pyganim, it's fairly straightforward. But my problem lies with how I build my game, it starts pyganim's animation 60 times a second, therefore it never animates at all (according to the human eye). I need help in terms of how do I tell if an animation is currently playing or not, then call the play or not afterwards?

My code:

```
class gameStart(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.background = pygame.image.load("BG" + str(level) + ".png")
    self.player = pygame.image.load("2_scaled.png")
    self.icon = pygame.image.load("1_scaled.png")
    self.background_S = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (width, height)) #Scale the background to match the screen resolution
    screen.blit(self.background_S, (0,0))
    screen.blit(self.player, (0, height/2))
    screen.blit(self.icon, (0,0))
    self.position = self.player.get_rect()
    self.health = 100
    #Setup the players Idle, Attack, Attack 2 and Death Animations
    self.PlayerIdleAnim = pyganim.PygAnimation([('2_scaled.png', 1), ('3_scaled.png', 1), ('4_scaled.png', 1), ('5_scaled.png', 1), ('6_scaled.png', 1)])
    updateDisplay()

def move(self):
    global rightPressed
    global leftPressed
    global facing
    global frame
    leftPressed = False
    rightPressed = False
    if keyPressed(K_a):
        leftPressed = True
    elif keyPressed(K_d):
        rightPressed = True
    elif not keyPressed(K_a):
        leftPressed = False
    elif not keyPressed(K_d):
        rightPressed = False


    if rightPressed and (self.position.x < width - 200):
        self.position.x += moveSpeed
        screen.blit(self.background_S, (0,0))
        self.PlayerIdleAnim.stop()
        screen.blit(self.player, (self.position.x, height/2))
        if not facing:
            self.player = pygame.transform.flip(self.player, True, False)
            facing = True
        updateDisplay()
    elif leftPressed and (self.position.x > 20):
        self.position.x += -moveSpeed
        screen.blit(self.background_S, (0,0))
        self.PlayerIdleAnim.stop()
        if facing:
            self.player = pygame.transform.flip(self.player, True, False)
            facing = False
        screen.blit(self.player, (self.position.x, height/2))
        updateDisplay()
    elif not leftPressed and not rightPressed:
        if not facing:
            self.PlayerIdleAnim.flip(True, False)
            self.PlayerIdleAnim.play()
        else:
            self.PlayerIdleAnim.play()
    """elif rightPressed and not (self.position.x < width - 200):
        rightPressed = False
    elif leftPressed and not (self.position.x > 200):
        leftPressed = False"""




game = gameStart()

while not gameQuit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameQuit = True
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            gameQuit = True
    game.move()
    updateDisplay()
    fpsClock.tick(fps)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation will never technically run, because it is always stuck on the first frame. But if you do want to find out if it will run if you give it time to switch frames just make a loop activated only when a key is pressed that lets the animation run. something like ...

```
def anim_test():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    while run == true:
        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```